# How to limit processor time for specific web site running under IIS on windows web server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

What tool could I use to limit processor time for specific web site running under IIS on windows web server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *limit* CPU Time by giving that website its own application pool and configuring it accordingly:

- http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/cpu

Unfortunately this does not provide a *peak*, where it would *cap* the worker process and allow it to run at 100% of your defined limit (say 60% of CPU is your limit). Once it hits your defined limit it executes a defined *action* of "log" or "kill process".

I am curious as to why you would want to cap the process? If you have IIS related processes eating up 100% CPU you may be better off investigating that issue. You could use the Debug diagnostics tool to troubleshoot:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919791

Answer (score 1):

You can get greater granularity over IIS and just about any other process using the Windows System Resource Manager.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732553.aspx